# how to get the eslint report by rules instead of by files?

Tags: eslint

how can I get the eslint report by rules instead of by files?

I have tried with the different built in formatters but I haven't found a config to change the way it outputs the report

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a [custom formatter](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-custom-formatters) to get the output you want. Given the `results` array, you would be able to aggregate the `messages` in each `result` into a map by `message.ruleId`.